# In python, how to transfer file in bytes with GRPC in a right way?

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

For some reason, I want to transfer file (not in stream) with grpc in python. The protobuf and python code are as follows

- protobuf

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
package xxxx;

service gRPCComServeFunc {
  rpc sendToClient(FileRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}

message FileRequest {
  FileInfo info = 1;
  bytes chunk = 2;
}

message FileInfo {
  int32 sender = 1;
  int32 state = 2;
  string timestamp = 3;
}
```

- python

```
def get_file_content(path_file):
    with open(path_file, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
    return content

def pack_file_request(state, chunk):
    request = gRPC_comm_manager_pb2.FileRequest(
        info=gRPC_comm_manager_pb2.FileInfo(
            sender=0,
            state=state,
            timestamp=""),
        chunk=chunk
    )
    return request

...
chunk = get_file_content(path_file)
request = pack_file_request(state, chunk)
stub.sendToClient(request)
```

- First, the server reports error as follows

```
...
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
        details = "Received RST_STREAM with error code 8"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer 0.0.0.0:50078 {created_time:"2023-01-04T22:02:11.242643217+08:00", grpc_status:1, grpc_message:"Received RST_STREAM with error code 8"}"
```

- It looks like the message is sent successfully, but refused by the remote client at 0.0.0.0:50078.
- So I guess it's caused by the file chunk, and this time I send the message **without chunk** as follows

```
def pack_file_request(state, chunk):
    request = gRPC_comm_manager_pb2.FileRequest(
        info=gRPC_comm_manager_pb2.FileInfo(
            sender=0,
            state=state,
            timestamp=""),
    )
    return request
```

And it works. Therefore I guess I cannot directly read the file and pass it to grpc services in python.

So how should I read the file and pass it to the parameter `chunk` in grpc service `sendToClient`?

Comment: When I get that right, you dont send some content in the second attempt, right? The problem is most likely in the encoding of the value in chunk.

Comment: @sim , thanks, finally I found that's because the file is larger than 4MB, which is the default max length in GRPC. Then I modify the max_receive_message_length in the server and it works.